# CSS: Scrolling Background

Tags: css

I have been using [this site](http://html5up.net/aerial) as a template for my page but I am having difficulty changing the background image. I have recreated just the background on this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ckxvfv0b/). The current background works because the top has a single color and the sides make it look like the image is continuous.

Here is the relevant CSS Code:

```
0% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
100% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(-2250px, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-2250px, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(-2250px, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(-2250px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-2250px, 0, 0);
}
```

Is there a way to make it so the background scrolls to the right and once it reaches the end, it scrolls back to the left? It is very difficult to make an image look "continuous" when it scrolls.

Comment: An animation like ping-pong?

Comment: Yes, I suppose you could call it that. I also realized I could always just copy the image but flip it so it looks continuous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually almost the same functionality as one of my first scripts ever, by leveraging the `right` CSS property.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  text-align: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.marquee {
  -webkit-animation: rightLeft 20s linear infinite;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rightLeft {
  0% {
    right: 0;
  }
  50% {
    right: 80%;
  }
  100% {
    right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="marquee" src="http://html5up.net/uploads/demos/aerial/css/images/bg.jpg" />
</div>
```